# How to put download option on show page in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to put download functionality on my show page but sign is not coming on page also it download automatically when page is open without clicking anywhere and only image download is not working . 
show form -

```
<tr>
  <th><strong>Download Document</strong></th>
  <td><%= link_to '',download_screenshot_path(id: issue_request.id),class: 'btn btn-xs fa fa-download' %></td>

  <th><strong>Download Image</strong></th>
  <td><%= link_to '',download_screenshot_image_path(id: issue_request.id),class: 'btn btn-xs fa fa-picture-o' %></td>
</tr>
```

controller method -

```
def show
  @issue_request = IssueRequest.find(params[:id])
  send_file @issue_request.document1.path,
            filename: @issue_request.document1_file_name,
            type: @issue_request.document1_content_type,
            disposition: 'attachment'

  @issue_request = IssueRequest.find(params[:id])
  send_file @issue_request.document2.path,
            filename: @issue_request.document2_file_name,
            type: @issue_request.document2_content_type,
            disposition: 'attachment'
end
```

Comment: **but sign is not coming on page** - what sign you are expecting on the page ? You have supplied nothing to `link_to` to name your download link.

Comment: i mean download button is not coming in page .

Comment: Give a name to your link:  `<%= link_to 'Download',download_screenshot_path(id: issue_request.id),class: 'btn btn-xs fa fa-download' %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the `send_file` in the show method, that will do the download immediately. You want a separate action.

I assume you have the routes set up for your download paths, they should be set up to be something like...

```
get '/screenshot', to: 'issue_requests#download_screenshot', as: 'download_screenshot'
```

Then in the `issue_requests_controller.rb`  you would have

```
def download_screenshot
  issue_request = IssueRequest.find(params[:id])
  send_file issue_request.document1.path,
            filename: issue_request.document1_file_name,
            type: issue_request.document1_content_type,
            disposition: 'attachment'
end
```

And do something similar for the `download_screenshot_image` with a different path to a different controller action.

This way it's only when the `link_to` is clicked that the download happens.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify text into link_to tag , otherwise button will not appear
like this

<%= link_to 'Test Button',download_screenshot_path(id: issue_request.id),class: 'btn btn-xs fa fa-download' %>